# How to find graphic file to edit social icon

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a WordPress theme called Divi.  This isn't a WordPress question.  There are a number of provided social media icons, but I need a Soundcloud icon, and that is not provided.  I'm not understanding how these icons are populating the page as they don't seem to be graphics, but rather are a font?  However, I am unable to tell from the source code what is going on (inexperience).

What I'm trying to do is either add an icon of my design, or replace an existing icon.  Can someone help point me in the direction if where I should be looking within my files to find the actual icons?

You can see a live site here and the icons are at the top right:
http://rattletree.com/wordpress2/

The dev code has this for the Facebook icon:

```
<ul class="et-social-icons">

<li class="et-social-icon et-social-facebook">
    <a href="#" class="icon">
        <span>Facebook</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

And the css has this:

```
.et-social-facebook a.icon:before {
content: "\e093";
}
#top-header .et-social-icon a {
font-size: 14px;
}
```

So that makes me think this is a font, but I don't know how or where I can edit that font?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'd recommend doing a Google search for "Soundcloud Icon SVG", downloading and modifying the SVG as necessary (with Illustrator for instance) and then using [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38177046/1309582) as a guide for how to add it to Divi.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the font pack you are using:

http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/elegant-icon-font

It doesn't look like it has an icon for soundcloud, but you could use the cloud one:

```
&#xe002;
```

So just add this to the style sheet:

```
.et-social-soundcloud a.icon:before {
    content: "\e002";
}
```

Also, here's a tutorial:
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/how-to-use-and-embed-an-icon-font-on-your-website

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've seen those tutorials and that cloud, but it's not the actual icon, so I don't think it will convey what we want.  What I need to know is how to get into that font file and be able to make an edit to the file?

Comment: I wouldn't reccommend it. Unless you are familiar with font editing software, it would be a difficult task to add another icon to it. I would suggest just uploading a little icon image to your media library in wordpress, then referencing it from the css file as a background image.

Comment: However, if you are looking for the font file, you will find it in your theme folder: /includes/builder/fonts/ETmodules_v2_4. There will be 4 types, EOT, TTF, WOFF & SVG.

Answer (score 0):

To add an icon of your design, add the following code to your stylesheet.

```
#top-header .et-social-icon.soundcloud a {
    width: 15px;
    height: 25px;
}
.soundcloud a.icon:before {
    content: "";
    background: url('https://placehold.it/15x25') 100% 100% no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Make sure you create an icon, add the icon image to theme folder and update the url in the above code to point to that image.

Also add the class `soundcloud` to your menu in WordPress backend.